# ESB Mule HTTP throws doSelect error

Tags: mysql, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I have ESB mule flow(running in Mule 3.7.0 CE) with HTTP request node which throws me an below error. The Mule flow has request config as like below.

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api_requests/secure_request" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
                <http:request-builder>
                    <http:query-param paramName="addRequest" value="#[flowVars.requestpayload]"/>
                </http:request-builder>
                <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
            </http:request>
```

The Error as follows

```
Mar 29, 2016 9:45:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner notifyConnectionException
SEVERE: doSelect exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.HttpTransactionContext.getAsyncHandler(HttpTransactionContext.java:155)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.getWorkManager(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:119)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.getThreadPoolFor(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:90)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Though this error, we are receiving response. What could be the issue for this error message.

Comment: What mule version are you using?

Comment: Have you fix it? I have same problem